# Randomizing starting row input in imacro

Tags: imacros

If I have a !DATASOURCE csv input file with 50 first+last names in two columns, how do I write an imacro that grabs a random first & last name from the list to plug into an online database? I know that once the random row is selected I can just use `CONTENT={{!COL1}}` and `{{!COL2}}`, but how can I randomize which name is selected every time I run the imacro?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use these commands:

```
SET randomRow EVAL(1+Math.floor(Math.random()*50))
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{randomRow}}
```